Run cloud-build triggers with Node.js library
I have a manual regional cloudbuild trigger, that uses Cloudbuild repositories (2nd gen) to make connections with github. I also need to pass substitution variables to the trigger.
Following this example to achieve the same:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-devtools-cloudbuild/samples/generated/v1/cloud_build.run_build_trigger.js
As far as the repoSource goes (https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.triggers/run), the API is trying to leverage cloud source repositories.
Is there a way I can use 2nd gen repositories with the API/library?
Just to try out, if I can at least run the trigger:
    const buildRequest = {
        projectId: projectId,
        triggerId: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${triggerLocation}/triggers/${triggerName}`
    }

    console.log("Build request:", buildRequest);

    try {
        const [operation] = await cloudBuildClient.runBuildTrigger(buildRequest);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Build started', operation });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Build initiation error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to start build' });
    }


But, this gives me Build initiation error: Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.

Apparently, I was overcomplicating it with the build request
Also, need to provide triggerId instead of trigger name
The updated buildRequest:
const buildRequest = {
    name: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${triggerLocation}/triggers/${triggerId}`,
    source: {
        substitutions: buildSubstitutions
    }
}

Good idea to do a getBuildTrigger if facing a similar issue:
const { CloudBuildClient } = require('@google-cloud/cloudbuild');
const cloudBuildClient = new CloudBuildClient();

const request = {
   name: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${triggerLocation}/triggers/${triggerId}`
};

const response = await cloudBuildClient.getBuildTrigger(request);
console.log(response);

